# Rails 4 x Bootstrap 3: Dismissible alerts not working

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, alert

In my Rails 4 app, I use Bootstrap 3.

In particular, I use Bootstrap to display and style flash messages.

This is what I have in my `application.html.erb` layout file:

```
<div class="flash">

    <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
      <div class="alert alert-<%= key %> alert-dismissible">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <%= value %>
      </div>
    <% end %>

</div>
```

Flash messages do appear when expected, and disappear after 2 seconds, thanks to the following JS code in `custom.js` file in `assets/javascript`:

```
$('document').ready(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.flash').slideUp();
  }, 2000);
});
```

Only issue, I cannot figure out how to get a "x" button to allow users to hide a flash message once they have seen it.

[Bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#alerts) says:

> Requires JavaScript alert plugin For fully functioning, dismissible
>   alerts, you must use the alerts JavaScript plugin.

I followed the link and arrived [there](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#alerts) but did not understand which plugin we were talking about.

This is the content of my `application.js`:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require moment
//= require bootstrap-datetimepicker
//= require bootstrap/dropdown
//= require bootstrap/modal
//= require bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add `//= require bootstrap-sprockets` to your `application.js` file

```
...
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require_tree .
```

`bootstrap-sprockets` is the bootstrap JavaScript support.

Comment: That works, thanks a lot. Just a quick question, if I may: in your experience, is there a best practice as to how to order the various `//= require` in the `application.js` file? Because I read a couple of times about cases where app were breaking / not working because `//= require bootstrap-sprockets` was before `//= require bootstrap` or the other way around.

Comment: the `//= require` determines the sequence how files are loaded. The `//= require`s are processed from top to bottom. Finally the `//= require_tree .` loads all other files, not yet required, in arbitrary order. `bootstrap-sprocket` depends on `jquery` that's why it has to come after that. Regarding the `bootstrap` before `bootstrap-sprockets` or the other way round I cannot tell as I haven't used it yet.